# python function returns nothing

Tags: python-3.x, function, beautifulsoup

I'm writting a function that sould be able to scrap links from people names contained in an html file. I wanna warn you all beforehand, i know it's ugly, i know it's long, and i also know it's certainly not the most elegant way of doing it. But this is the best i could come up with, since i'm a total beginner in python.

Here's my code:

```
file = 'C:/users/me/webpage.html'

def get_links(file):
    import codecs
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    f = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8')
    soup = bs(f.read(),'lxml')
    link_list = []
    A_list = soup.find(string = 'Rob Agerbeek').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Rob Agerbeek', 'Albert Ammons', 'Andrews Sisters', 'Winifred Atwell'])
    A_links = [i.get('href') for i in A_list]
    link_list += A_links
    B_list = soup.find(string = 'Bob Baldori').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Bob Baldori', 'Marcia Ball', 'Deanna Bogart', 'James Booker', 'Eden Brent', 'Dave Brubeck'])
    B_links = [i.get('href') for i in B_list]
    link_list += B_links
    C_list = soup.find(string = 'Francis Craig').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Commander Cody and His Lost Planet Airmen', 'Francis Craig', 'James Crutchfield', 'Ray Charles'])
    C_links = [i.get('href') for i in C_list]
    link_list += C_links
    D_list = soup.find(string = 'Francis Craig').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Caroline Dahl', 'Cow Cow Davenport', 'Blind John Davis', 'Neville Dickie', 'Fats Domino', 'Floyd Domino', 'Dorothy Donegan', 'Georgia Tom Dorsey', 'Dr. John', 'Champion Jack Dupree', 'Big Joe Duskin'])
    D_links = [i.get('href') for i in D_list]
    link_list +=D_links
    E_list = soup.find(string = 'William Ezell').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['William Ezell'])
    E_links = [i.get('href') for i in E_list]
    link_list += E_links
    F_list = soup.find(string = 'Wayne Federman').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Wayne Federman', 'Ella Fitzgerald', 'Frankie Ford', 'Ernie Freeman', 'Keith Emerson'])
    F_links = [i.get('href') for i in F_list]
    link_list +=F_links
    G_list = soup.find(string = 'Blind Leroy Garnett').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Blind Leroy Garnett', 'Harry Gibson', 'Harry Gibson'])
    G_links = [i.get('href') for i in G_list]
    link_list +=G_links
    H_list = soup.find(string = 'Willie Hall').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Willie Hall', 'Jools Holland', 'Camille Howard', 'Bob Hall', 'Henri Herbert', 'John Lee Hooker', 'Nicky Hopkins'])
    H_links = [i.get('href') for i in H_list]
    link_list += H_links
    J_list = soup.find(string = 'Elton John').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Elton John', 'Pete Johnson', 'Louis Jordan'])
    J_links = [i.get('href') for i in J_list]
    link_list += J_links
    K_list = soup.find(string = 'Michael Kaeshammer').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Michael Kaeshammer', 'Shizuko Kasagi', 'Joe Krown'])
    K_links = [i.get('href') for i in K_list]
    link_list += K_links
    L_list = soup.find(string = 'Booker T. Laury').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Booker T. Laury', 'Jerry Lee Lewis', 'Meade Lux Lewis', 'Liberace', 'Little Richard', 'Little Willie Littlefield', 'Cripple Clarence Lofton', 'Professor Longhair'])
    L_links = [i.get('href') for i in L_list]
    link_list += L_links
    M_list = soup.find(string = 'Memphis Slim').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Memphis Slim', 'Big Maceo Merriweather', 'Moon Mullican'])
    M_links = [i.get('href') for i in M_list]
    link_list += M_links
    N_list = soup.find(string = 'Romeo Nelson').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Romeo Nelson', 'Charlie Norman'])
    N_links = [i.get('href') for i in N_list]
    link_list += N_links
    P_list = soup.find(string = 'Bill Payne').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Bill Payne', 'Oscar Peterson', 'Piano Red', 'Pinetop Perkins', 'Ross Petot', 'Sammy Price', 'Professor Longhair'])
    P_links = [i.get('href') for i in P_list]
    link_list += P_links
    R_list = soup.find(string = 'Boogie Woogie Red').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Boogie Woogie Red', 'Maurice Rocco', 'Walter Roland', 'Leon Russell'])
    R_links = [i.get('href') for i in R_list]
    link_list += R_links
    S_list = soup.find(string = 'Ulf Sandström').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Ulf Sandström', 'Bob Seeley', 'Luca Sestak', 'Omar Shariff', 'Robert Shaw', 'Freddie Slack', 'Huey "Piano" Smith', 'Clarence "Pine Top" Smith', 'Charlie Spand', 'Otis Spann', 'Speckled Red', 'Roosevelt Sykes'])
    S_links = [i.get('href') for i in S_list]
    link_list += S_links
    T_list = soup.find(string = 'Gene Taylor').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Gene Taylor', 'Montana Taylor', 'George W. Thomas', 'Hersal Thomas', 'Allen Toussaint', 'T. Rex', 'Stephanie Trick', 'Big Joe Turner', 'Ike Turner'])
    T_links = [i.get('href') for i in T_list]
    link_list += T_links
    W_list = soup.find(string = 'Rick Wakeman').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Rick Wakeman', 'Tuts Washington', 'Kenny "Blues Boss" Wayne', 'Vince Weber', 'Robert Wells', 'Clarence Williams', 'Jabo Williams', 'Mitch Woods'])
    W_links = [i.get('href') for i in W_list]
    link_list += W_links
    Y_list = soup.find(string = 'Jimmy Yancey').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Jimmy Yancey'])
    Y_links = [i.get('href') for i in Y_list]
    link_list += Y_links
    Z_list = soup.find(string = 'Silvan Zingg').find_parent('ul').find_all(title = ['Silvan Zingg', 'Axel Zwingenberger', 'ZZ Top'])
    Z_links = [i.get('href') for i in Z_list]
    link_list += Z_links

    return link_list
```

The main issue here is that every line works independently, i'm getting the desired output with this code, however when i wanna run it inro a function, it returns nothing, no error, no None, just nothing, absolutely no result, just a blank output. I would highly appreciate if someone could shine a light for me here.

Thank you all

Comment: All functions return at least a None or raise an error. This one returns `link_list` so... show us how you know it doesn't. Trim the example after adding `B_links` so we don't have to wade through extra stuff and show how its used so we can see where the issue is.

Comment: Can you show us some example of the `webpage.html` file so we can see the formatting and maybe help with some more efficient code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function returns the correct value, probably there is a fault in the way you pass this value to the other function. 
A way would be to make another variable. Or just pass the method itself.

```
otherFunction(get_links(file))
```

Or

```
link = get_links(file)
otherFunction(link)
```

Might not be it but return and local variables gave me a hard time when I was learning so I guess worth mentioning.

Comment: This is just speculation. OP hasn't given enough information to say.